# Yet another double slit experiment

Tags: double-slit-experiment, wave-particle-duality

If single particles shot one at a time at the double slit do exhibit wave-like behavior, then if we put another screen right between the slits and perpendicular to the first screen, won't we also see that some of the particles form a pattern on the second screen as well? (if this is silly please remove my question)

[image]

Comment: ", won't we also see that some of the particles form a pattern on the second screen as well??" What does this mean?

Comment: the second screen  makes it two separate single holes with their independent  diffraction pattern, if the slits are narrow enough. On the vertical screen there will be spots uncorelated, the same as would be found on the second screen if one closed off sequentially each slit.  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/sinslit.html

Comment: @annav if we put a screen which doesn't let any particles go through, what you've said is correct. However what would happen if we put a screen which only lets 80% or 90% or whatever through as to make a weak measurement? This is much more interesting than a stone wall.

Comment: @gonenc  have a look at this http://phys.org/news/2011-01-which-way-detector-mystery-double-slit.html ( after the sixth paragraph). Transparency will affect the coherence and to the extent that the coherence is lost the double slit interference will be lost.

Comment: @annav well that is a shame then!

Comment: @Harry Wilson I wanted to say that if the particles behave like waves and the second screen could record being hit by a particle then we should see particle hits on that screen as well as on the first screen

Comment: @anna v Thank you for the clarification, so basically this is not another Young Double Slit but a Fraunhofer Single Slit... please post your first comment as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second screen makes it two separate Fraunhofer [single slits](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/sinslit.html) with their independent diffraction pattern, if the slits are narrow enough. On the vertical screen there will be spots uncorrelated, the same as would be found on the second screen if one closed off sequentially each slit.

If the second screen were made partially transparent the degree of survival of the two slit pattern would depend on the percentage of beam coherence lost. Any scattering disturbs coherence. [This experiment](http://phys.org/news/2011-01-which-way-detector-mystery-double-slit.html) has used semi transparent covers on a double slit experiment :

> Although the electrons (which were shot one by one) could still pass through the filtered slit, the filter caused more of the electrons to undergo inelastic scattering rather than elastic scattering. As the physicists explained, an electron undergoing inelastic scattering is localized at the covered slit, and acts like a spherical wave after passing through the slit. In contrast, an electron passing through the unfiltered slit is more likely to undergo elastic scattering, and act like a cylindrical wave after passing through that slit. The spherical wave and cylindrical wave do not have any phase correlation, and so even if an electron passed through both slits, the two different waves that come out cannot create an interference pattern on the wall behind them.

Something similar would happen if the second screen were semitransparent.

Comment: 1) Aren't the Fraunhofer slits qualitatively wider than each of the double slits? 2) Possibly interesting thought experiment: What if screen 2 is a perfect mirror?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean some special screen 2 that "lights up" when hit from either side, then no, there won't be a pattern, because the length (or rather:time) from hole A to some spot on the screen will be the same as the length/time from hole B. There will be no destructive interference "on" the screen 2.

Comment: I upvoted your comment because it does clear up the fact that it would be no interference pattern on the screen 2 (perhaps I shouldn't have suggested correlation on screen 2 by using the word "pattern", maybe "trace of electrons" would have been better). I marked anna v's answer as accepted because it adds some more info.