# Heisenbergs uncertainty principle for photons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, photons, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

The Heisenberg uncertainty principle arises from the description of matter as being represented as a wave packets, and hence its fourier decomposition having a range of multiple wave numbers in its creation, giving rise to a range of momentum associated with a specific wave packet.

Since as I understand it, the de Broglie relation can be "derived" from $E=pc$ and $E=hf$ (which are about photons) and then postulating they hold for matter as well (I'm sure this way of thinking is not the full picture), from this the imagination of a wave function was born.

So a natural question is does the Heisenberg uncertainty principle apply for photons?

More specifically, does the photon have a specific wave function, comprised of many different wave numbers(and or frequencies), in order to create a localised wave packet.

The reason this has interested me is consider the following:

$\sigma_{x}\sigma_{p} \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}$

$E=pc$ ,
$E=hf$

$pc=hf$

If there are some range of frequencies that comprised the photons wave function, then I'm pretty sure it follows that

$\sigma_{p} c = h \sigma_{f}$

Substituting into the uncertainty principle

$$\sigma_{x}\sigma_{f} \geq \frac{c}{4\pi}$$

This predicts that the colour of light from a single slit diffraction for example should vary as you go along the diffraction pattern(since the uncertainty principles explanation for diffraction varies the momentum of the photon), for an actual noticeable colour difference the slit should be on the order of *10^-7 m

However I cannot find this happening anywhere online so something in my logic is not correct, I suspect this being my assumption on the form of the photon wave function

Comment: The uncertainty principle has nothing to do with quantum mechanics. It applies to all linear systems that can be described with wave-like phenomena, e.g. surface waves on water or acoustic waves. A single photon does not have a wave function. Only the ensemble of photons has a wave function. A photon does not even have a frequency, either. E=hf is a relationship between photon energy and the frequency of a monochromatic classical wave as observed in the photoelectric effect. You are simply mixing two different pieces of physics.

Comment: @FlatterMann  "A single photon does not have a wave function". AFAIK this is not correct. see https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0604169 .  Also this "A single photon does not have a wave function." is not correct. The photon is a quantum mechanical entity in the standard model of particle physics, of zero mass, spin one .https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model . as such it must  have a wavefunction for the QFT to work.

Comment: @annav I have built high energy physics detectors that have measured many trillions of photons. At most I got one energy, one momentum and one angular momentum value out of one of those measurements. What was the wave function of that photon?

Comment: It's possible to define a single photon Fock state for any arbitrary normalizable solution of Maxwell's equations. This is covered by introductory QFT. This is a single photon wave function in the same sense that a single particle state of the electron field can be considered an electron wave function.

Comment: @FlatterMann are you aware that the wave is a probability wave that the wave function discusses? Probability means that an individual event is not enough to check the measurements, but an accumulation is needed. see my answer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/421181/tagging-the-photons-on-double-slit-experiment/421189#421189

Comment: @AwkwardWhale The electromagnetic field doesn't behave like a single photon wave function. That's like fitting a circle to planetary orbits and calling it a day in classical mechanics without even trying epicycles, let alone Kepler and Newton.

Comment: @annav There is no such thing as a "probability wave". You can't even explain Stern-Gerlach with that concept. That's why we need the full Born rule. However, as soon as you mention probabilities, you are admitting that what you are really talking about is an ensemble. And that is all I am saying. A single quantum is simply not enough to characterize a quantum system. Technically not even an infinite number of quanta is because wave functions contain "too much information". We can never determine the phases.

Comment: @FlatterMann  look at the single photon at a time double slit figures and link to see what a "probability wave " is

Comment: @annav It doesn't matter how many photons are in the double slit. It doesn't show you anything else than the mean field theory aka Maxwell. Optical photons don't interact, hence the ensemble theory is identical to single photon counting. You can see this in the fact that Planck's constant is nowhere to be found and since you aren't doing correlation between multiple quanta, you aren't getting quantum field behavior any other way, either. The only experiments that are seeing quanta are emission and absorption experiments (Plank, photoelectric effect, anomalous magnetic moment of electron....).

Comment: @annav Apologies. In my last post I wanted to say "the mean field theory of the ensemble theory is identical to averages in single photon counting in this particular case". Once we are doing correlations as in quantum optics, Maxwell falls apart very quickly, of course. One can kick off an argument whether Elitzur–Vaidman rises to that level or not, but it would take something along the lines of two-photon coincidence to go beyond Maxwell in a meaningful way. As well intentioned as Feynman may have been with the double slit in his textbook, I think he jumped the shark a bit.

Comment: @FlatterMann If you are thinking of the so called "photons" of quantum optics, that is a different story. Their "photons" can have mass and have nothing to do with elementary particle QED theory. I pass.

Comment: @annav A photon is an irreversible energy exchange between the electromagnetic field in vacuum and an external system. An em field coupled to matter has quasi-excitations with different names like "polariton". That some authors don't keep with the conventions of solid state physics in this regard has nothing to do with physics. It's simply more poor notation that messes up beginner's intuition. I don't want to comment on that. You can't pass on serious quantum optics. A good mental model fits all of physics. Mine does. "Particles" do not.

Comment: @FlatterMann you seem to be giving a very disingenuous reading of what I've said, and also your point of contention is largely semantic, due to a heterodox interpretation of what the word photon is supposed to mean. The conventional definition is simply the quanta described by the number operator of the electromagnetic field. You can argue about whether such photons truly exist in the real world, but this is purely semantic and metaphysical anyway since quantum field theories are hardly a complete description of the universe to begin with

Comment: Regardless of this, free field states are a perfectly adequate description for the behaviour of the electromagnetic field in regions of space that are largely absent of matter, and such states have well defined particle number conceptually. The manifold of single photon Fock states has as much conceptual sense to be called a 'single photon wave-function' as the wave function of a single electron does.

Comment: @AwkwardWhale I was trying to be a little funny by exaggerating. Apologies if it didn't come over right. The difference between Copenhagen (which is what I am talking about) and things like "Which way did the photon go?" aren't semantics. They are essential to understanding QM. Neither can we do realistic physics with a single photon state. We need, at least, an emitter (an electron) and an absorber (another electron). We also always need two pieces to have relative physics to begin with... even in CM. Some simplifications are so simple that the bottom falls out. No offense intended.

Comment: @AwkwardWhale There are no "photons" in places without matter. The view of the photon as an atomistic constituent of the fields is very attractive and it's also false, both experimentally (it's unobservable) and theoretically because the Born rule doesn't apply and the free propagation is described by a path integral... which means that it's everything, everywhere, all at once. That's a consequence of the ensemble character of the theory but it has consequences for the physics of it.

Comment: @FlatterMann We have a basic disagreement. It does not matter if a model fits within errors everything, unless it is a TOE. As far as mainstream physics goes at present, the underlying level of all mathematical physics models is the standard model of particle physics. All other mathematical models are emergent from it.

Comment: @annav I am simply talking about Copenhagen, which happens to "fit" since 1926 or 1927. I don't know why this is such a big issue. Quasi excitations are conceptually also under investigation since the 1930s. My best guess is that some of their names were already established in the textbooks of the 1950s, like in Kittel's "Introduction to Solid State Physics", which I had to study like the bible for my undergrad exam. This has nothing to do with TOE, this is what generations of bench top physicists have been doing for almost a century now and it's all covered by "irreversible energy transfer".

Comment: "...measured many trillions of photons. At most I got one energy, one momentum and one angular momentum value out of one of those measurements. What was the wavefunction of that photon?" could be directly swapped photon for electron. Does the Copenhagen extremists not talk about electron's wavefunctions either?

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent All quanta are characterized by those half dozen physical properties. Wavelength, frequency etc. are mathematical properties of the ensemble description. We can, of course, find experimental ways of measuring them for suitable (coherent) multi-quanta systems. One should, however, never mistake the ensemble of a single-quantum system for a multi-quantum system. Sometimes they have the same properties and many times they don't. A cube of tungsten, for instance, can never be described by a single quantum ensemble of electrons.

Answer (score 1):

The colour of light is determined by its *frequency* as this is what determines the response of the detecting compounds in our eyes or any other detector. The relation $f\lambda=c$ applies only to infinite plane waves.  When a monochromatic beam passes through slits, its spatial variation is no longer a simple plane wave but its frequency remains unchanged.

Because the resulting wave must still satisfy the wave equation with an unaltered  frequency   the wave becomes a sum of infinitely many plane waves, all of which do have have the same wave*length*, but with infinitely many different *directions* of propagation. The infinite sum gives the diffraction pattern.

Where the uncertainly principle comes into play is when you have a wave that wa created by a source that was active only for a finite time. In that case the wave cannot consist of only one one frequency.   The finite-length wavetrain contains a range of frequencies whose bandwidth is inversely proportional to  its length. That length  is $c$ times the length of time that the source was switched on.

Answer (score 0):

The comment statement by Flatterman

> The uncertainty principle has nothing to do with quantum mechanics. It applies to all linear systems that can be described with wave-like phenomena, e.g. surface waves on water or acoustic waves.

is correct.

Photons are elementary point particles in the mainstream [standard model,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model), and as such cannot be studied in interactions with matter using classical mechanics and optics, it is necessary to use quantum mechanics. The frequency that is used to define a photon's energy, $E=hν$ does not describe an individual photon. It appears only in the accumulation of photons

[See here the experiment](https://www.sps.ch/artikel/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/) one photon at a time going through two slits.

[image: singlephot]

> Single-photon camera recording of photons from a double slit illuminated by very weak laser light. Left to right: single frame, superposition of 200, 1’000, and 500’000 frames

Single photons scattering off the two slits are described mathematically by a Feynman diagram of a point photon interacting with the field (due to the atoms on the sides of the slits),and then act as free particles hitting the screen and leaving a point footprint. There is no "waving" of a single photon.Then as they are accumulated, an interference pattern appears. It is in this pattern that the Heisenberg constant $h$ is relevant and one can connect the interference pattern with the frequency $ν$ of the laser light used in the experiment.

Wave packets are a different story and are useful , [see here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/uncer.html#c2) a discussion  .