# Quantum Physics photon emission rate

Tags: quantum-mechanics

According to the formula, intensity $I = \frac{\left( dN dt \right) \left( h c \right)}{\lambda A}$, with $\lambda$ being the wavelength and $A$ the area. When wavelength increase, KE decrease, assuming constant intensity, so why when a photon has lesser KE, the number of incident photons per unit time $\frac{dN}{dt}$ increases which dosent logically make sense?

Comment: Why not? If I have a blue light source and a red light source with the same power, is there any reason to expect them to emit the same number of photons?

Comment: You are confusing light with photons. Light is not a summation of photons light emerges from    a quantum mechanical confluence of photons. I do not want to repeat myself, see my answer here  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/759459/heisenbergs-uncertaintly-principle-for-photons/759589#759589